# Display settings are not saved

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 17.10, settings

I just installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my Asus n56vz laptop with two external displays connected and found that display settings (primary display, positions, etc.) are not saved (are not kept after reboot). Also, I faced with a problem editing display positions (drag and drop doesn't work well).

Possibly, it happens because of two configurations in `monitors.xml` file. The first one is active when laptop lid is closed and has two external displays. The second one is active when laptop lid is opened and has three displays (internal and external ones).

Update, I tried to update 'monitors.xml' manually, it looks like that it is not used at all.

Update, I was able to fix it, and to enable my laptop to remember display settings by disabling laptop lid opening handling setting 'IgnoreLid=true' in '/etc/UPower/UPower.conf' file.

There are several similar questions on askubuntu, but no clear answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use NVIDIA drivers you must change your settings from there.I would recommend using `xrand` command to change your settings, you can make auto run script or a key combination to switch between settings using `xrand` command.

Edit: To fix it set `IgnoreLid=true` in `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` file!

Comment: Thank you! I tried to use NVidia control panel with the same result (display settings are not saved). And, I am thinking about creating of xrandr script for my display settings. Though, I hoped that such simple issue can be solved without scripting:)

Comment: Just in case if it is interesting for somebody, xrandr line for my display settings (one display above another) "xrandr --output VGA-1-1 --auto --primary --output HDMI-0 --auto --above VGA-1-1"

Comment: this can be solved without script, but it will take more time to find where the problem is and solving it.

Comment: I did it without scripting by  setting 'IgnoreLid=true' in '/etc/UPower/UPower.conf' file!

Comment: Thats great to hear, I will edit my answer with your comment so people can benefit from it, is that okay?

Comment: `xrandr` (not xrand; X11 *R*esize and *R*otate) does not save settings. It is a sandbox for playing with the settings, the same as the Displays plugin for the Settings tool. I feel this is not a canonical answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following on Ubuntu 22.04 with an external display connected to an  NVIDIA GPU via HDMI.
open nvidia-settings:

```
$ sudo nvidia-settings
```

Then under nvidia-settings Configuration tab, check:

- Include X Display Names in the Config File

Your system should save the current display configurations.

Comment: This worked for me (also Ubuntu 22.04)